# How to show all of minibuffer commands history in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, minibuffer, input-history

I see I can go back history of command by using "M-p" in minibuffer. But I want to see all of command I used in minibuffer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The variable is `command-history`, not `minibuffer-history`.

You can use `M-x list-command-history`.  Just customize option `list-command-history-max`, if you want to see the whole history.

Or look directly at variable `command-history` using `C-h v`.  But see option `history-length`, which controls how many commands to keep in `command-history`.

Answer (score 4):

It's held in `minibuffer-history` variable.
For a graphical view, use `helm-minibuffer-history` from `helm` package.

Comment: I entered "minibuffer-history" and then "C-j" in scratch buffer. But it only shows ("7" "8" " " "=>" "%d " "204" "188" "%1d " "1" "777" "wdired"). What is this?

Comment: That's a list of your minibuffer history. Isn't this what you expected?

Comment: Yes, that's not what I expected. It seems that is the history when I entered "C-x r N". I forgot when it was. But I entered more command from then. Where the left go?

Comment: "M-x list-command-history" seems work. But it doesn't show all of history of minibuffer.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repetition.html#Repetition) explains how to repeat the n-th previous command and how to view history:

> `M-x list-command-history`
>
> Display the entire command history, showing all the commands `C-x <ESC> <ESC>` can repeat, most recent first.

And [according to this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html#Minibuffer-History) you can set the maximum length of the minibuffer history:

> The variable `history-length` specifies the maximum length of a minibuffer history list; adding a new element deletes the oldest element if the list gets too long. If the value is `t`, there is no maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Helm, then it would be:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-minibuffer-history)
```

The equvalent version of `selectrum + consult`:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'consult-history)
```